# How can I change the Xcode project so I don't have to run it in SUDO Mode

Tags: xcode, permissions, sudo

I can only run my Xcode project in sudo mode. If I don't run it in `sudo`, Xcode can't read the project file. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran these command in my terminal.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 my directory
```

This allowed me to open up my project in without running sudo.